# Grading layers according to CMYK color codes in Attribute Table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, color

I have been trying for some time to color grade a geological map according to CMYK values given in the attribute table. I have not yet succeeded. I am certain that is just a simple line of code that is needed and hope some of you can help me.

I am currently using QGIS 3.14. The column that I want to grade to colors after are the `"cmykFargekode"` column.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at `data defined override` (of symbol colours).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you mention you're a rookie, here is a detailed step-by-step guide :

### Open the Layer Styling panel to set a data-defined color

[image]

- Right click on the layer in the layer tree, and click Properties... to open the above panel
- Click on Symbology (1) to open the layer styling tab
- Click on Simple Fil (2) to configure symbol
- Click on the button on the right of the fill color field (3)
- Click on Edit to open the expression builder

### Define a conversion function

Here are the CMYK to RGB conversion formula

```
r = 255 * (1-c) * (1-k)
g = 255 * (1-m) * (1-k)
b = 255 * (1-y) * (1-k)
```

The QGIS expression builder already includes a bunch of color-related functions, but unfortunately for you, none which convert a cmyk string to a rgb string. But you can easily add your own functions.

[image: create_function]

- Click on the Function Editor tab (1)
- Replace the content of the function panel (2) with the following code:

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Color')
def cmyk_to_rgb(cmyk_string, feature, parent):
    """ Convert a cmyk color string to a rgb color string """
    c,m,y,k = [int(val)/100 for val in cmyk_string.split(',')]
    r = str(int(255 * (1-c) * (1-k)))
    g = str(int(255 * (1-m) * (1-k)))
    b = str(int(255 * (1-y) * (1-k)))
    return ",".join((r,g,b))
```

- Click on the "Save and Load Functions" button
- You can now use the newly-defined cmyk_to_rgb in the expression builder

### Use the Expression Builder

[image: Expression]

- Almost done now. Go back to the Expression tab (1)
- Type `cmyk_to_rgb( "cmykFargekode")` in the Expression Field (2)
- Press Ok (3)

This should do the trick.

---

### Edit

QGIS provides a function `color_cmyk` that takes 4 integers (or string representation of integers) as input. As [J. Monticolo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372588/137840) pointed out, you can actually use the default QGIS functions to build an expression that performs the task. The whole "Define a conversion function" step can thus be avoided.

```py
eval('color_cmyk(' || "cmykFargekode" || ')')
```

**Explanation**:

- `"cmykFargekode"` is expanded to say `'47,0,80,0'`
- It is then concatenated (`||` syntax) with `'color_cmyk('` and `')'` which gives the string `'color_cmyk(47,0,80,0)'`
- This string is evaluated with the `eval` function and tadaa!

The other suggested approach relies on the `with_variable` syntax

```py
with_variable('cmyk', string_to_array("cmykFargekode"),
    color_cmyk(@cmyk[0], @cmyk[1], @cmyk[2], @cmyk[3])
)
```

**Explanation**:

- `"cmykFargekode"` is expanded to say `'47,0,80,0'`
- `string_to_array` converts the string to an array `['47', '0', '80', '0']`
- `with_variable` stores this array in a variable called `'cmyk'`, which is then accessible in the second part of the expression as `@cmyk'
- The second part of the expression `color_cmyk(@cmyk[0], @cmyk[1], @cmyk[2], @cmyk[3])` is evaluated

Comment: You have built-in functions for that, they are maintained, faster (C++) ... This answer is well documented yes, but not the simpliest and better answer IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

Why so complicated [Yoann Quenach de Quivillic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/372587/93097) ?

1. **Step 1** (the same) : Open the Layer Styling panel to set a data-defined color
2. **Step 2** : copy the formula in the expression builder `eval('color_cmyk(' || "cmykFargekode" || ')')`

---

**EDIT**

2. **Step 2** (*bis*) : here the formula without `eval()` function :

   ```py
   with_variable('cmyk', string_to_array("cmykFargekode"),
       color_cmyk(
           @cmyk[0],
           @cmyk[1],
           @cmyk[2],
           @cmyk[3]
       )
   )
   ```

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of the with_variable syntax! Neat. Also, nice trick with the eval function.